# How to use sci-kit Decision trees for unsupervised classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wish to use Decision trees to group a set of excel spreadsheets into families of clusters using features such as file size, number of sheets, name of sheet 1.

I wish to use the scikit-learn decision tree classifier. Each sample I supply is a python dict. Here is an example of one sample of my decisionData list

```
{'numSheets': 3, 'sheetName': 'Main', 'size': 1}
```

I have about 300 samples to classify and I want to do this using DecisionTreeClassifier. Because the data includes strings I use

```
vec = DictVectorizer()
train = vec.fit_transform(decisionData).toarray()
```

I also wish to use the entropic criterion for splitting the samples and start with a max_depth of 3

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',max_depth=3)
```

Now I need to call

```
clf = clf.fit(train, labels)
```

What I do not know is what form the vector of labels should take. Is this simply an ID for each sample.

Also, when I get a result, how do I extract the leaf on the tree for each sample that has been supplied. I am concerned about how to un-transform the labels so that I can understand what the classification was.

All of the documentation I can see is for supervised learning where a known target is supplied so any help would be great.

Comment: Decision Tree is a supervised algorithm. You'll need to provide ground truth labels. If you want to do something without supervision, you should use clustering, like [KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).

Comment: That's a pity. I know that it should be possible to build a decision tree which works by choosing the feature which splits the data best in terms of entropy gain maximisation and then repeating until no improvements can be made

Comment: How would you calculate an entropy gain without labels?

Comment: There are non-parameteric entropy estimators you could use, and they are discussed in http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/155552/decisionForests_MSR_TR_2011_114.pdf but I don't think they are really mainstream.
@Dominic why do you want to use decision trees?

Comment: I think I have misunderstood Decision trees. I wanted to use decision trees because my data is a combination of numerical and categorical types so distance metrics do not have a meaning. So Kmeans does not seem natural.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. Regarding your distance measure: you can either discretize your numerical variables and use a distance (or similarity) measure for categorical data (decent starting point: http://www.academia.edu/2691588/Similarity_measures_for_categorical_data_A_comparative_evaluation), or convert your categorical data to numeric and use a numeric measure (cosine similarity tends to be pretty good).